# Contradiction regarding Mr. Miyagi's age

Tags: cobra-kai

In Season 3 Episode 4 of Cobra Kai, about 20 minutes in, Daniel says that he is currently the same age that Mr. Miyagi was when they met:

[image: Screenshot of scene with subtitle of Daniel saying that he is the same age as Mr. Miyagi was when he met him]

Throughout the series it is clear that the current events take place 30 years after the original events. Even granting that those events might have spanned a couple of years, Daniel couldn't have met Mr. Miyagi more than 32-33 years or so ago. Given that he was in his mid teens at the time, that would make him most probably in his mid to late 40s, at most 50.

Yet in Season 1 Episode 5, at about 25 minutes in, Daniel visits Mr. Miyagi's grave and the tombstone clearly shows that Mr. Miyagi was born in 1925:

[image: Screenshot of scene showing the tombstone with the birthyear of 1925]

That would have made Mr. Miyagi around 60 at the time he met Daniel in the mid 1980s (according to the opening scene in Season 1 the match against Johnny occurred at the end of 1984), making him a good 10-15 years older than Daniel is during the current events of the series.

How can this contradiction be explained?

Comment: your premise is wrong, there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

According to many online sources ([this one for example](https://thekaratekid.fandom.com/wiki/Daniel_LaRusso))

> Daniel was born in New Jersey on December 18, 1966

so he is almost 41 years younger than Mr Myiagi. In 1984 he was 18 years old and Mr Myiagi would be indeed 59. (At the time of the tournament, which is in summer, Daniel would still be 17).

The Cobra Kai series [starts in 2018](https://thekaratekid.fandom.com/wiki/Daniel_LaRusso#Cobra_Kai_.282018.29), so 34 years after they met.

37 years later (which is now, 2021) Daniel is 55 years old so he is only wrong by around 4 years, close enough to say "we're the same age".

Comment: Karate seem to have kept him looking young I guess. :-D

Comment: Three points off the top of my head (I think there are further issues that will require more time to investigate): 1) If Daniel was 18 when it started, how did he compete in an under 18 tournament, not once but twice? 2) Just from what transpires during the Cobra Kai series there is not three years between when it started and when Daniel made the comment. It starts during the school year, centers a lot on that summer, and then the major brawl occurs on the first day of the next school year. Daniel’s comment comes in the aftermath of this fight, so probably a few weeks later.

Comment: 3) Your answer is not consistent with the site you cite which explicitly states that Daniel was 48 at the beginning of Cobra Kai.

Comment: @Alex Daniel was 17 at the time of the first tournament - his birthday is in December... Also, my math checks out, regardless of what the site says it's his age at the start of the series.

Comment: @Alex also wikipedia corroborates it: "The series takes place 34 years after the first film. Now in his 50’s, Daniel is happily married ..."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_LaRusso

Answer (score 0):

Poor writing.

Nariyoshi Miyagi, originally referred to as Hideo Miyagi in the first movie as seen on his dog tags (another inconsistency), was said to be born on June 9, 1925.  In 1984, the time of the first Karate Kid movie, he would have been 59.  Pat Morita, at the time, was 52 when the movie was filmed; making the actor 7 years *younger* than the character.

Daniel LaRusso was said to be born on December 18, 1966.  In 1984, that would have made him 17 at the beginning of the first Karate Kid movie.  Ralph Macchio was actually 23 at the time the movie was filmed; making the actor 6 years *older* than the character.

When Season 3 of Cobra Kai was filmed, Ralph Macchio was 58.  That was about the age Miyagi was when the two met.  However, Season 3 takes place in 2019, 35 years after LaRusso was 17.  This would have made his character roughly 52, which would be 7 years *younger* than Miyagi was when they met.

So, you could say LaRusso was the same age as Morita was, which would be accurate but doesn't fit into the Karate Kid universe since there is no Morita, only Miyagi.  So, you fudge the ages to make the point of equating the events of the movie with the events of the TV show, and hope no one points it out on a question & answer board.  :-D